# How to intercept encrypted XMPP traffic?

Tags: ssl, proxy, xmpp

I have an mobile chat application which is using xmpp protocol for messageing. I am able to intercept http traffic of Application with traditional proxy like burp suite(After bypassing ssl pinning). This proxy tool is not able to intercept xmpp traffic. I tried to intercept xmpp traffic with wireshark but traffic is encrypted. Is there any method to handle this problem? Or any tool to intercept xmpp traffic.

Comment: Xmpp has several encryption protocols. What encruption protocol you need to intercept?

Comment: @gapsf xmpp tls